# Solr count is incorrect

Tags: solr, apache-zookeeper, solrcloud, cassini

Background: 2 out of 3 of our `Zookeeper` machines snapped which caused my `SOLR` system to collapse. I added new `Zookeeper` machines and updated each `SOLR` machine config with the new `Zookeeper` machine.

After this, I started the `SOLR` and used admin page to query `*:*` which returned a different number every time I queried the pool.

So, I purged all the records in `SOLR` cloud and ran a `batch-job` to populate all the data again from Oracle to SOLR. (Everything looked good).

Problem: I have a daily `batchjob` which updates the `SOLR` with `DELTA(Inserts + Updates)` from `Oracle`.

Since this instance. The number in `SOLR` pool are not matching the `DELTA(insert + update)`. For ex: even though 1000 records were updated or inserted on a day, SOLR counts differ by more than 10000.

The numbers returned by `*:*` are not matching. We have tried purging the records multiple time. Things look good when we insert the record for the first time after purge but as soon as updates start happening, numbers don't match.

There are no Duplicate Records. and If I query for a specific record we get the correct record but facet numbers are wrong too.

Is the index file is corrupted?

Comment: 1. How many Solr instances for the cluster?
2. How many shards?
3. How do you do indexing? Through SolrJ or anything else?

Comment: 25 instances in the cluster, 3 Shards. I have a Spring batch job which reads the records and updated them in `SOLR`

Comment: did zk track the proper status of all the instances?

Comment: @s.xie, yes it did. and the new zk also have all the instances. cloud looks good.

Comment: Nothing can ring a bell from these facts. A few suggestions: 1. solr config commit strategy. 2. check solr logs, if replication is properly done. 3. maybe rebuild solr on exiting zk ensemble?

Comment: @s.xie, just following up on this again. found that there are duplicate documents in our shards with different `_version_`. I ran the solr queries with `distrib=false` on 2 different nodes from 2 shards and they both returned 2 documents with different `_version_`. any insights?

Answer (score 0):

Try optimizing your index. I was also facing the same issue and optimizing the index fixed it.

```
      curl http://hostname:8980/solr/<core>/update?optimize=true
```

Some more info on optimize:

http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrPerformanceFactors#Optimization_Considerations

PS: Note that an optimize is expensive. You should not run it more than once daily.

Comment: I have tried optimizing the index. That did not change anything so far.

Comment: just following up on this again. found that there are duplicate documents in our shards with different `_version_`. I ran the solr queries with `distrib=false` on 2 different nodes from 2 shards and they both returned 2 documents with different `_version_`. any insights?